# HTTP url redirects as HTTPS on selenium test run

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I pass an URL to load a website, say, `http://yoururl.com`, it redirects to `https://yoururl.com`

I mean, passing an URL with HTTP automatically redirects as `https://yoururl.com` in the browser URL.

```
@driver.get("http://yoururl.com")
```

Browser used: Chrome

Is there a way to stop redirecting the HTTP url as HTTPS?

Comment: So what is the question here,  whether it should or should not ? :)

Comment: I don't want to redirect to https, cos I test the application locally

Comment: @kakurala how to fix it?

Comment: This is probably not caused by selenium but by the web browser or by the web it self

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chrome 63 and above versions will no longer take `HTTP` with domain `.dev` since you are in the `local/dev` environment.

https://iyware.com/dont-use-dev-for-development/

> Chrome 63 (out since December 2017), will force all domains ending on
>   .dev (and .foo) to be redirected to HTTPS via a preloaded HTTP Strict
>   Transport Security (HSTS) header
>   https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of reasons this would happen.

1. Redirection at load balancer or reverse proxy level.
   This can be fixed by altering web server or LB configuration.
2. As browsers getting smarter everyday, when you open an https url is browser then next time if you even want to open http url it'll by default go to https because browser already knows that the site supports https as well. So it'll prefer to use secured communication rather text when it is available.

Here is some help for second case https://superuser.com/questions/565409/chrome-how-to-stop-redirect-from-http-to-https